# wordpress optional post/page content loading

Tags: wordpress

I want to check some parameters before loading a page or post content. If parameter match with a specific value i want to take some action like running some javascript, notifying users, locking contents etc.

I don't want to edit theme. Please suggest some hook or snippet to do it separately instead of modifying existig code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the_post action hook or filters like the_content or the_title, it depends on what you want to do.

The complete list of all hooks: http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook

About using the_post hook: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-use-the_post-action-hook